# pandas : high values converted to nan when passing to numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Sorry if this question is very easy to answer, I'm a newbie to python and pandas. 
However, searching on stackoverflow and google in general, I cannot find the answer to this question :

I have a dataframe in pandas with columns with numbers of relatively different magnitude.

df['x'] is of the order of ~40, while df['x_2'] is of the order of 2.5e6.

When reaching for these values, x_2 is automatically converted to nan while x is not :

```
 X=df.loc[:,['x','x_2']].values
```

X[:,0] contains floats while X[:,1] contains nan.

The problem seems to come from the fact that x_2 is written with an exponent : e.g 2.5e6. However, at the end of the day, I cannot find how to obtain a float in my numpy array in X[:,1]. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Upgrade your packages.